# windows.onload vs resize different width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to adjust several elements in width and height in relation to window width. So I am using

```
window.onload = function() {
    slideSizeUpdate();
};
$(window).resize(slideSizeUpdate);
```

to call my function.

After window resize everything is displayed correctly - but not onload. I guessed that this had something to do with the window-width-value.

So, I printed the width value of window and recognized that - onload - my window width had a value 'x' and when I resized for 1px left or right value 'x' of window width increased / decreased + / - 18px.

I assume that this causes the problems on my website onload. Does anybody know the reason for this and has anybody a solution how to fix it? That would be great!

**EDIT**

Its not that onload doesn't work at all. Its just the wrong values that it seems to get when it reads out the window width.

Comment: If you're following general jQuery writing rules you might had have put your code into DOM ready (i.E. `$(function(){});`). This will make onLoad never used as the binding happens after all work is finished.

Comment: Are you assigning anything else to `window.onload` which would remove the event? You really should just add the onload with jQuery.

Comment: @Zentoaku The code does not have to be in onready...

Comment: @epascarello This isn't what I said. Just opposite. If you'll bind onLoad in onReady then it will never happen.

Comment: Why? onready fires before onload.

Comment: My bad, too tired to think right. I need to leave SO for today :)

Comment: There is only `slideSizeUpdate();` in my window.onload. It's the same behavior with `$(window).on('load resize',function()`.`$(document).ready(function()`doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post the output of the following: `window.onload = function() { console.log( "before calling", /*width*/ ); slideSizeUpdate(); console.log( "after calling", , /*width*/ ); };`?

Comment: Its both the same value (after adding vertical scrollbar). I recognized that all values are correct now. Its obviously a problem with the carousel-script that I use. The carousel works with values defined in a css-file (static) and after resize (dynamic). This is just kind of strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
   slideSizeUpdate();
}).resize(); // trigger resize when page is loaded
```

Comment: That trigger line is not when loaded,that is when that code is running. Not sure why that would make any difference than the load just firing.

Comment: This triggers the resize event when page is loaded. Any confusion?

Comment: Why did you do "`.resize();`"?

Comment: If you don't then it will only be called on resize and but if you do it then first resize function would be called and then after you manually resize the browser then it won't have any problem...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this scenario:

- Some of the content is hidden via CSS. The resulting page is short and no horizontal scrollbar is required.
- You calculate the window width on `load` event at which point scrollbars are not there.
- You un-hide the content and now the page is tall and requires horizontal scrollbar.
- The width of the window decreases by 17px (usual width of scrollbar) without you noticing.

If this is the case then one solution is to force the window horizontal scrollbar using CSS. You can use the following (although I recommend searching more on StackOverflow):

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```